# Magento 2: Admin Formatting/Rendering problem

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, css

Magento 2.1.9
CentOS 7.0 x64 eaPHP56

Got a very odd issue with admin after a Cpanel upgrade. Frontend works perfectly but the admin has rendering issue. It affects all screens but is worst for anything that's listed in a table. All CSS files load ok, no permission issues.

I've cleared static files, cleaned and flushed cache, redeployed static content with correct languages **en_GB en_US**, compiled, cleaned local cache, cleared Cloudflare cache but still no joy. I'm at a loss now so anyone who has the faintest idea, please comment :) Thanks

[image: Admin Format Issue]
[image: How it Should Look]

Answer (score 0):

Try to run these commands in your root installation folder:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

chmod -R 775 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
mage cache:flush &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy;
chmod -R 775 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Comment: I will try them a bit later when the sites a bit quieter, thank you. Haven't used mage commands before, just normal php bin/magento. Can you let me know what they do that's different to the normal code for upgrade and deploy, flush etc? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. Admin still not functioning correctly. I have my web server guys checking settings. Figure a mime setting maybe incorrect. It's odd as a lot of the screen is formatted correctly, and front end has no issues at all. The main container seems to be where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved.

CSS file styles.css was being cut short before it got to the browser. This was being caused by Auto Minify in Cloudflare settings. Javascript and HTML remain both ticked, but unticking CSS Auto Minify had an immediate effect after fully refreshing cache on client PC.